# Multiple key declarations for enums in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm adding a Text component in Typescript, which can be of some different kinds of type: `<Text type='h2'>Hello World</Text>`.

I'm using a styles object that has those types as keys, so that I can derive the proper styles from them. This type should this be only one of several possibilities.

```
import React from 'react'
import { colors } from '../../config'

const getKeyValue = <U extends keyof T, T extends object>(key: U) => (obj: T) => obj[key]

const styles = {
  h1: {
    fontSize: "46px",
    lineHeight: "64px",
    fontWeight: 300,
  },
  h2: {
    fontSize: "34px",
    lineHeight: "48px",
    fontWeight: 300,
  },
  h3: {
    fontSize: "28px",
    lineHeight: "40px",
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  h4: {
    fontSize: "23px",
    lineHeight: "32px",
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  h5: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "32px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  h6: {
    fontSize: "13px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  h7: {
    fontSize: "11px",
    lineHeight: "16px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  subtitle1: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  subtitle2: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    lineHeight: "16px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  body1: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  body2: {
    fontSize: "13px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  button: {
    fontSize: "13px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  caption: {
    fontSize: "11px",
    lineHeight: "16px",
    fontWeight: 400,
  }
}

interface Style {
  fontSize: string;
  lineHeight: string;
  fontWeight: number;
}

interface Styles {
  h1: Style; h2: Style; h3: Style; h4: Style; h5: Style; h6: Style; h7: Style;
  subtitle1: Style; subtitle2: Style; body1: Style; body2: Style; button: Style; caption: Style;
}

interface Props {
  children: string;
  type: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'h7' | 'subtitle1' | 'subtitle2' | 'body1' | 'body2' | 'button' | 'caption';
  color?: string;
  ellipsis?: boolean;
  fontWeight?: any;
  onChange?: any;
}

const Text = ({ children, type, color = colors.darkGrey, ellipsis = false, fontWeight }: Props) => {

  const style = {
    ...getKeyValue<keyof Styles, Styles>(type)(styles),
    color,
    minHeight: 25, // TODO: remove this arbitrary height
    textOverflow: ellipsis ? 'ellipsis' : 'none',
    overflow: ellipsis ? 'hidden' : 'none',
    whiteSpace: ellipsis ? 'nowrap' : 'none',
  } as React.CSSProperties

  if (typeof fontWeight !== 'undefined') {
    style.fontWeight = fontWeight
  }

  return <div style={style} >{children}</div>
}

export default Text
```

This is all well and good, but I'm declaring the keys of the styles object three times:

- In the styles object itself
- In the Styles interface
- In the declaration of type `type`

That feels redundant, but I'm too much of a noob on Typescript to know how I can do better.

Can this be done in a more concise / better way, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined `Styles` and `type` in relation to the inferred type of the `styles` constant. To get the type of the constant we can use [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-extraction.html#the-typeof-type-operator) and to get the keys of the type we can use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-extraction.html#the-keyof-type-operator). Then we can use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to create the `Styles` type (record is a type with a given set of keys all of the same type)

```
type StyleType = keyof typeof styles
type Styles = Record<StyleType, Style>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-XeDAYNRbfn7VPO3Pu72816U-K4Ni4GgUGBg1vc0ad2ry47K-HTeX3X2lx8V6tSCtyDaWQoEwdABEKGBYgESM7TVOgoDaegAG5mjfD54MQlCpWrJwqF4EATCQKAUIA0hILAcDILiTQ2AooQVDUDRyKQdQ4BiOIaDI2jKKghJEEsaB5BECCoJoijdBEuIrEA-YiNAtABAABRwMAlEjNA0mAbh5CIKgnAwqhkOaZinEkpAxKQLDLwgbhoAAfn0mAEMMqykG4VpVOAGgHLgBsbNQKgrP7aYfJQKg2Cs6gAGE0jCxhQvCkiImoOhrNsqA+MSOB5BQKBlAAcSIRxjgqFYUIoFL4E0aR4GEGwso0rSdLkXRmN0Sh0vojroBoAA6HK8sK9hdDcjyaC8+jQO4GgkF0YK+nPJxlIgVT-A8ZJmkiVL2IEJIdl6g7GBYdguD4JARHsVizJoCSqPiWxmJcGwdpoFwXm6qAXhANpdRmDYOV0AB6QGtAAeQAEVBpwiBACAADcBBgTSlFykwQygXK2HSWEdlkGRQYRkDbIAdycUbgE8pQ7IIcnKfwOAnHwKhqCQfAXnhuSSbJ9yKfGqmCE0+R5DkenGeZ9o2Z2YnNNkQowDA7mxom6mmYgYmMbAUWCHF1nvjgFAlGQdAYF6qLCkKZaKNgYB4nIVJgA0GxmNY+b4AAQkEYR8F4BQkEwEV5HwNxxx23rXcm78YCxO24CIGBeCgKhRHkYA4bYu7BESHaVjgKxEka7TdJWERAZTuHpNI6RIFgbK-ZQXhuCqmqgA)